# Powershell script is error when run Release Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a release pipeline on Azure DevOps and got a PowerShell script error message "Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"  as in the image below although I could connect to virtual machine by running Registration script on the PowerShell administrator.Please help me to pass this case

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBjYG.png)

And this is my powerShell config on Azure :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0YtW.png)

Comment: Are you using self hosted agent to run this pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the below command to install the IIS server feature in Azure DevOps pipeline like below:-

I created one Self-Hosted Agent and ran your command inside the self hosted agent VM just to check if it runs correctly :-

[image]

I ran the same command in my Azure DevOps YAML pipeline but added Start-Process command to start PowerShell task in elevated state as Administrator.

**Script:-**

```yaml
trigger:

- main

  

pool:

name: Default

  

steps:

- script: echo Hello, world!

displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  

- script: |

echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.

echo See https://aka.ms/yaml

displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- task: PowerShell@2

inputs:

targetType: 'inline'

script: |

$script = "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole"

Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-Command', $script
```

With  both the commands:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- main

  

pool:

name: Default

  

steps:

- script: echo Hello, world!

displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  

- script: |

echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.

echo See https://aka.ms/yaml

displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

  
  

- task: PowerShell@2

inputs:

targetType: 'inline'

script: |

$script = "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole"

"Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName ASPNET45 -All"

Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-Command', $script
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]